# UISearchbar squished in UINavigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a search bar set as the title view in my navigation bar. In the initial view the search bar is evenly spaced in the middle with buttons on both sides. In this view the back button pushes the search bar so that it is uneven. I've tried getting rid of the text of the back button, but it still didn't work to spread the search bar out. [Squished search bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yufvL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently needed to solve the same issue. I ended up creating a UIBarButtonItem with the back button image asset, and setting that as the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`. This button press then calls `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` to pop the viewController off the stack

Comment: I will try that. There is no provided back button image is there?

Comment: It worked for me! To get the image I went here https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/ and downloaded the resources for Sketch then found the back icon and imported that into my project.